# How do I embed django forms into my css design?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am creating a website and already finished the frontend. Now I want to handle a form submit post request using python. I am trying to do this using django, but I can't figure out how I would

1. attach CSS classes, onchange eventhandlers and IDs to the django forms
2. insert divs and other html elements in between the django input elements within a single form

This is my current frontend:

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off">
<p class="sub-header">Or just leave Us a Message:</p>
<div>
    <div id="contact-layout">
        <div class="input-container">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
            <div class="input-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-container">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            <div class="input-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-container">
            <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
            <div class="input-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-container">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type your message here..." id="message-input"></textarea>
        <div class="input-bar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="sub-header" id="user-image-header">Attach some images:</p>
    <div id="file-upload">
        <span class="form-button">Choose Files</span>
        <input id="upload" type="file" onchange="LoadImage(this)" name="image" accept="image/*" multiple>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="delimiter"></div>
<input class="form-button" type="submit" id="contact-submit" value="Submit">
<p id="submit-thanks">Thanks for submitting!</p>
```

as you can see I have a few "normal" html text inputs, a text area and an input for multiple image files.
In django I linked my static css files and setup my html frontend as a django template.

My django form looks like this so far:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
   name = forms.CharField()
   email = forms.CharField()
   phone = forms.CharField(required=False)
   subject = forms.CharField(required=False)
   message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

When I insert it into my frontend, It obviously doesn't look that good, as I have no Idea how I would represent my rather complex form design using django.

Could you point out how you would do this or maybe link a few good guides on how to approach something like this?

Also if possible provide some code examples :)

FYI I am familiar with python but I have never used django before, so maybe I am missing something obvious as for me it seem kind of overwhelming in it's complexity as a framework.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: Django comes "batteries included" so there's indeed a lot to learn - it's not that  much that it's "complex" (it's actually rather simple considering all the features), but that it's "wide" ;-)

Comment: Check this out too https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Your links combined with nigel222's answer really helped me to get a basic understanding of Django and to finally get it all working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting point is to familiarize yourself with what a default Django form generates. Here, for example, I was finding out for myself about the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget:

```
>>> class ZForm( forms.Form):
...  foo = forms.MultipleChoiceField( choices=(('A','AA'),('B','BB'), ('C','CC')),   widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple )
...
>>> z = ZForm()
>>> z.as_p()
'<p><label>Foo:</label> <ul id="id_foo">\n    <li><label for="id_foo_0"><input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="A" id="id_foo_0" />\n AA</label>\n\n</li>\n    <li><label for="id_foo_1"><input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="B" id="id_foo_1" />\n BB</label>\n\n</li>\n    <li><label for="id_foo_2"><input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="C" id="id_foo_2" />\n CC</label>\n\n</li>\n</ul></p>'
>>>
```

If you want to style it with css, the css ids generated by Django make it fairly.  straightforward to describe any elements with css locators.If you don't want the default Django layouts, you can generate the form field-by-field in your template, or you can learn about [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (especially, layout helpers) which I wholeheartedly recommend.

As for where to inject css into Django, there are various ways, but a common one is through a block called something like `css` in your base template. The view template will look something like

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <!-- code to render your form -->
    ...
{ %endblock content %}

{% block css %}
    /* base.html provides the surrounding style tags */
    /* block.super inherits the css common to all pages using base.html */                              

{{block.super}}

    /* additional styling for the form rendered in block content */

    #id_foo label {
        /* styling for labels on the foo field only */
        whatever;
    }

{% endblock css %}
```

In passing my own `base.html` also always loads Jquery (unsurprisingly in a block called `scripts` so I can per-template-override or augment should I need to) and has a block `onready_js` that gets rendered in this context, which saves an awful lot of easily-mistyped boilerplate around what can be a trivial Jquery snippet

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(  function() {
{% block onready_js %}{% endblock onready_js %}   
   }); 
</script>
```

and you just put any per-template Jquery you need to be executed when the view is invoked  into that block.

Answer (score -1):

You can develop frontend and backend seperately in django. You can create a form on frontend and style it and handle it on your backend as

```
def my_route_handler(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # do your processing
    # return
```

There is no need to embed the django form in frontend.

Comment: Well, if you want to have a maintenance hell, never give your user proper feedback on form's errors etc, yes, I guess you can say that you don't strictky _need_ to use the form for rendering... Now while we're at it, you don't strictky need them in the views either, you can as well  just code all the validation / sanitization etc code yourself in the view ;-)